# How to solve this task in functions?

Tags: function

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define ALPHABET 26

 int isPermutation()

{

int perm[ALPHABET] ={0};
int i;
char ch;
scanf("%c",&ch);
for(i=0;i<ALPHABET;i++)
{

  perm[ch-'a']++;

    scanf("%c",&ch);
    if(ch<'a'||ch>'z')
    {
        return 0;
    }
}


for(i=0;i<ALPHABET;i++)
{
    if(perm[i] != 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
       return 1;
    }

}
return 0;
}
int main()
 {
   printf("Enter ABC permutation\n");
   if(isPermutation()==1)
  {
    printf("your input is valid permutation\n");
  }
  else
  {
   printf("your input is invalid permutation\n");
   }
  return 0;
  }
```

Hi,I need to write a code which checks if an input of 26 characters is a permutation of the letters a-z.My idea was to define an array which initializes all of his elements as zeros but when I enter a certain char between a-z the 0 should become 1 in the appropriate place but for right inputs such as qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm the code doesnt work can you see my error?

Answer (score 1):

Your second `for` loop returns when `i`=0, without checking any other letters of `ALPHABET`.  This is because the `if` in that loop returns 0 if the test succeeds, but returns 1 if it fails; thus, the loop never gets to progress past `i` being 0.

Comment: what does that mean ? and what do I need to do in this case?

Comment: You can start by explaining what it is you want this loop to do; then we can see about how to get it to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a space to the scant in loop as below :
     scanf(" %c",&ch);

This is because the when you reading characters using scanf, it reads all the types of characters one by one, including the special characters like "enter". Therefore, in this case it reads a character in the first scanf and "enter" in the next scanf.

You can instruct the scanf to ignore the special characters by prefixing %c by a space character.

And of course the second loop need to be rectified as it is running only once.

Comment: how can I rectify it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a flag variable. And use it in ur loop. Anytime, the array value is 0, raise the flag and quit the loop.

Eg :

```
int flag =0;  
for(i=0;i<ALPHABET;i++)  
{  
    if(perm[i]!=1)    
    {  
        flag =1;  
        break;  
    }      
}    
if(flag)  
    return 0;  
else  
    return 1;
```